# getElementById() not returning correct string

Tags: javascript, textarea, getelementbyid

I am trying to grab the text from the textarea and it returns something but it returns nothing, no string.. When I enter a string into the textarea and click the button, it still returns nothing.

```
var name;
name = document.getElementById('username').value;

function action() {
document.getElementById("theIMG").src = "https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + name;
console.log("Working");
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username here!"></textarea> <br />
        <button id="submit" onClick="action()">Submit</button>
        <br />
        <img id="theIMG"></img>
```

Comment: show us the html too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `getElementById` inside the `action` method - that `value` won't persist as the textbox changes:

```
function action() {
    var name = document.getElementById('username').value;
    document.getElementById("theIMG").src = "https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + name;
    console.log("Working"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time of execution of your code, value is "" only. And it will not change irrespective you change the value in html as you are not updating it in your script. Hence, you need to update your code to following

```
function action() {
    var name = document.getElementById('username').value;
    document.getElementById("theIMG").src = "https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + name;
    console.log("Working");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define name in the function itself, like this:

```
var name;


function action() {
name = document.getElementById('username').value;
document.getElementById("theIMG").src = "https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + name;
console.log("Working");
}
```